# Draw dynamic shapes iOS at very high rate

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I'm trying to create a sort of "radar" that would look like this :

[image: first radar]

The idea is that the blue part will act like a compass to indicate proximity of stuff to the user. The shape would be narrow, long and blue when the user is far from the objective, and become shorter, thicker and red when he gets closer, as shown below:

[image: second radar]

To achieve this, I drew a few circles (actually I tried IBDesignable and IBInspectable but I keep getting "Build failed" but that is another subject)

My question is : Is this possible to draw the "cone" part that is supposed to change its dimensions at a high rate without risking lag ?
Can I use UIBezierPath / AddArc or Addline methods to achieve this or I am heading to a dead end ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two approaches:

1. Define complex bezier shapes and animate use `CABasicAnimation`:

   ```
   - (UIBezierPath *)pathWithCenter:(CGPoint)center angle:(CGFloat)angle radius:(CGFloat)radius {
       UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

       CGPoint point1 = CGPointMake(center.x - radius * sinf(angle), center.y - radius * cosf(angle));

       [path moveToPoint:center];
       [path addLineToPoint:point1];

       NSInteger curves = 8;
       CGFloat currentAngle = M_PI_2 * 3.0 - angle;

       for (NSInteger i = 0; i < curves; i++) {
           CGFloat nextAngle = currentAngle + angle * 2.0 / curves;
           CGPoint point2 = CGPointMake(center.x + radius * cosf(nextAngle), center.y + radius * sinf(nextAngle));
           CGFloat controlPointRadius = radius / cosf(angle / curves);
           CGPoint controlPoint = CGPointMake(center.x + controlPointRadius * cosf(currentAngle + angle / curves), center.y + controlPointRadius * sinf(currentAngle + angle / curves));
           [path addQuadCurveToPoint:point2 controlPoint:controlPoint];
           currentAngle = nextAngle;
           point1 = point2;
       }
       [path closePath];
       return path;
   }
   ```

   I just split the arc into a series of quad curves. I find cubic curves can get closer, but with just a few quad curves, we get a very good approximation.

   And then animate it with `CABasicAnimation`:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
       [super viewDidAppear:animated];

       CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
       layer.fillColor = self.startColor.CGColor;
       layer.path = self.startPath.CGPath;
       [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
       self.radarLayer = layer;
   }

   - (IBAction)didTapButton:(id)sender {
       self.radarLayer.path = self.finalPath.CGPath;
       CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
       pathAnimation.fromValue = (id)self.startPath.CGPath;
       pathAnimation.toValue = (id)self.finalPath.CGPath;
       pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false;

       self.radarLayer.fillColor = self.finalColor.CGColor;
       CABasicAnimation *fillAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"fillColor"];
       fillAnimation.fromValue = (id)self.startColor.CGColor;
       fillAnimation.toValue = (id)self.finalColor.CGColor;
       fillAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false;

       CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
       group.animations = @[pathAnimation, fillAnimation];
       group.duration = 2.0;
       [self.radarLayer addAnimation:group forKey:@"bothOfMyAnimations"];
   }
   ```

   That yields:
   [image]
2. The other approach is to use simple bezier, but animate with display link:

   If you wanted to use a `CAShapeLayer` and a `CADisplayLink` (which is like a timer that's optimized for screen updates), you could do something like:

   ```
   @interface ViewController ()

   @property (nonatomic, strong) CADisplayLink *displayLink;
   @property (nonatomic) CFAbsoluteTime startTime;
   @property (nonatomic) CFAbsoluteTime duration;
   @property (nonatomic, weak) CAShapeLayer *radarLayer;

   @end

   @implementation ViewController

   - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
       [super viewDidAppear:animated];

       CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
       [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
       self.radarLayer = layer;
       [self updateRadarLayer:layer percent:0.0];
   }

   - (IBAction)didTapButton:(id)sender {
       [self startDisplayLink];
   }

   - (void)updateRadarLayer:(CAShapeLayer *)radarLayer percent:(CGFloat)percent {
       CGFloat angle = M_PI_4 * (1.0 - percent / 2.0);
       CGFloat distance = 200 * (0.5 + percent / 2.0);

       UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
       [path moveToPoint:self.view.center];
       [path addArcWithCenter:self.view.center radius:distance startAngle:M_PI_2 * 3.0 - angle endAngle:M_PI_2 * 3.0 + angle clockwise:true];
       [path closePath];

       radarLayer.path = path.CGPath;
       radarLayer.fillColor = [self colorForPercent:percent].CGColor;
   }

   - (UIColor *)colorForPercent:(CGFloat)percent {
       return [UIColor colorWithRed:percent green:0 blue:1.0 - percent alpha:1];
   }

   - (void)startDisplayLink {
       self.startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
       self.duration = 2.0;
       self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleDisplayLink:)];
       [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
   }

   - (void)handleDisplayLink:(CADisplayLink *)link {
       CGFloat percent = (CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - self.startTime) / self.duration;
       if (percent < 1.0) {
           [self updateRadarLayer:self.radarLayer percent:percent];
       } else {
           [self stopDisplayLink];
           [self updateRadarLayer:self.radarLayer percent:1.0];
       }
   }

   - (void)stopDisplayLink {
       [self.displayLink invalidate];
       self.displayLink = nil;
   }
   ```

   That yields:
   [image]

Comment: Thanks @Rob for the clear and detailed answer. I got this working in Swift and will paste the code in a separate answer. Now I have to map my item distance to this to get this done, will post the code on github if I succeed :)

Comment: Outstanding answer (voted.) I do notice that the OPs sample images have the curved part of the shape be an arc of a much smaller radius circle, where your images are pure "pie slices." It looks to me like the OPs images are a subsection of a small radius circle (a circle cut by a chord) combined with a triangle, but your answer is a good start.

Comment: Your approach of using 8 quadratic beziers is nice and simple. Do you know how close that holds to a true circle? I've seen write-ups that say 4 cubic beziers result in a shape that only differs from a true circle by much less than 1%, but your results certainly look perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Re number of beziers, I just tried 8 and overlaid this with a traditional arc, and they seemed to be closer than my eyes could detect, so I declared success. But the number of beziers is a variable (I kept my code flexible in this regard), so he can experiment with whatever number of beziers he wants. All I know is that two is too small, and eight looked great with negligible performance impact. I've found that even fewer beziers are needed if you use quadratic beziers, but the calculation of the control points is more cryptic, so I kept it simple here.

Comment: Re shape of the outer radar, I did that consciously. I thought (rather presumptuously, I admit) this was closer to what I inferred his intent was, rather than relying on his mockup. But he can use whatever center for the outer arc that he wants, as you know.

Comment: Rob is right, my mockups were quickly drawn and rather ugly. The pie slice is exactly what I needed and it looks better in my opinion

Comment: @Rob: I cannot rotate the pie slice around the screen's center, any clue why ? I wonder what point is considered to be the center of that pie slice

Comment: Oops never mind: For whoever it might interest, set the radarLayer's frame equals to the view's frame to have it rotate around the center !

Answer (score 4):

You should probably use one or more `CAShapeLayer` objects and Core Animation.

You can install the `CGPath` from a `UIBezierPath` into a shape layer, and you can animate the changes to the shape layers, although to get the animation to work right you want to have the same number and type of control points in the shape at the beginning and ending of your animation.

Comment: Unfortunately, because the angle of this pie wedge is changing, this won't work. I think he'll have to animate with `CADisplayLink`. If the angle didn't change, then a simple `CABasicAnimation` would have done it, but not in this case.

Comment: @Rob: Thanks for pointing this out. Du you think SpriteKit could help me here ? Because I never worked with CADisplay Link. I sure could give a try with a fixed angle as a start

Comment: @Rob, it should still be possible to use a CABasicAnimation. You could build the arc by hand using cubic bezier curves rather than using the arc command. (You'd just need to build the arc out of the same number of bezier segments in all cases.)

Comment: (Arcs don't work with arbitrary changes in start/end angle because internally it uses different number of cubic bezier sub-paths depending on the angle span of the arc, so the number of control points can change.) If you build your arc by hand then you can keep the number and type of control points constant.

Comment: @DuncanC - I'd suggest you try updating your answer with a working example of that, where the angle of the arc is changing. I think you'll find it's more complicated than you think. I think display link will be much easier, but to each his own. I'll post display link example.

Comment: @Rob, I have done this sort of thing before, but I don't have code handy, nor do I have time to write a working example. Agreed it gets a little complex, but it is possible. (You need to look up the method for approximating a circle or arc of a circle using cubic beziers, and then write code that always generates 4 bezier segments even for narrow arcs.)